# When trying to convert a list of python dictionaries into a SQLite table I keep getting an error?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, dictionary

I'm attempting to convert a list of python dictionaries into an SQLite table, using the code below.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('stockData.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.executemany(f"INSERT INTO AAPL1M2021 (time,open,high,low,close,volume) VALUES (%(t)s,%(o)s,%(h)s,%(l)s,%(c)s,%(v)s)", data)
```

Whenever I run this code it returns the error below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-dce4eb1e6f6f> in <module>
      2 conn = sqlite3.connect('stockData.db')
      3 c = conn.cursor()
----> 4 c.executemany("INSERT INTO AAPL1M2021 (time,open,high,low,close,volume) VALUES (%(t)s,%(o)s,%(h)s,%(l)s,%(c)s,%(v)s)", data)

OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

I must be missing something because I can't seem to find a solution.

Here is a sample dictionary from the list of dictionaries.

```
{'v': 26666,
  'vw': 133.233,
  'o': 133.31,
  'c': 133.49,
  'h': 133.49,
  'l': 133.02,
  't': 1609750800000,
  'n': 87}
```

Comment: is `data` a dict as you show ?

Comment: Is that your thought or are you sure you can pass a dict and refer to the keys with `%(t)s` ? I can't find  documentation on this and regarding the error I think only `%s` is allowed and values should be in the right order

Comment: Just use `execute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) package doesn't use `%s` style formatting.  It uses `?` for positional placeholders or `:name` for keyword placeholders.

So your query might look like

```py
c.execute(
    "INSERT INTO AAPL1M2021 (time,open,high,low,close,volume) VALUES (:t, :o, :h, :l, :c, :v)", 
    data
)
```

Note that `executemany` is used for lists of arguments for executing mulitple queries.  For a single dict use `execute`; use `executemany` for a list of dicts.